# R-liked table implementation in python

Tags: python, r, implementation

I'm looking for an implementation of table, which is similar to database table or spreadsheet. An implementation that I need has to contain functionality such as get by row, get by column...

Example:

```
table = [('id', 'name'), (1, 'a'), (2, 'b')]
table.labels = ('id', 'name')
table.column('id') = (1, 2)
table.row(id=1) = (1, 'a')
```

I've been looking around and cannot any, I'm thinking about writing one for my own but just want to make sure before doing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python Pandas?

http://pandas.pydata.org/